# How to extract a linear slice from an image in OpenCV / EMGU

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I have an image and two points,
and I want to read the pixels between these two points, 
and resample them into a small 1x40 array.

I'm using EMGU which is a C# wrapper for OpenCV.
thanks,
SW

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emgu CV includes method in the `Image` class for sampling color along a line called `Sample`.

Refer to the [manual](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Documentation) for the definition. [Here's](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/eaaf9cad-1fbc-73bb-b190-d216c4edf6f4.htm) the link to `Image.Sample` in version 2.3.0.

You will still have to re-sample/interpolate the points in array returned from `Sample` to end up with a 40 element array. Since there are a number of ways to re-sample, I'll suggest you look to other questions for that.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). It will allow you to get the points in the pixel array that best approximate a straight line. The Wikipedia link also contains psuedo code to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

#### Rotate and crop

I'd first try to do it like this:

- calculate rotation matrix with (`GetRotationMatrix2D`)
- warp the image so that this line is horisontal (`WarpAffine`)
- calculate new positions of two of your points (you can use `Transform`)
- get image rectangle of suitable width and 1 px high (`GetRectSubPix`)

Interpolation here and there may affect the results, but you have to interpolate anyway. You may consider cropping the image before rotation.

#### Iterate over the 8-connected pixels of the line

Otherwise you may use the line iterator to iterate over the pixels between two points. See documentation for [`InitLineIterator`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_drawing_functions.html?highlight=line#InitLineIterator) (Sorry, the link is to the Python version of OpenCV, I've never heard of EMGU). I suppose that in this case you iterate over pixels of a line which was not antialiased. But this should be much faster.

#### Interpolate manually

Finally, you may convert the image to an array, calculate which elements the line is passing through and subsample and interpolate manually.